# How ZooKeeper provides sequential consistency

Tags: apache-zookeeper, distributed-computing, consistency

In [here](http://zookeeper-user.578899.n2.nabble.com/Consistency-in-zookeeper-tp7578531p7578533.html)
someone said:

> "even if you read from a different follower every time, you'll never 
>   see version 3 of the data after seeing version 4."

So if I have 3 nodes zookeeper quorum as below:

```
zk0 -- leader
zk1
zk2
```

Assume there is a value in quorum "3" and I have a client connects to `zk1`, then my client sends a write request (update "3" to "4") and `zk0` (leader) writes the value then subsequently received the confirmation from `zk1`. My client can see the new ("4"), because it connects to `zk1`.

Now my question is, if I switch my client from `zk1` to `zk2` (leader hasn't received write confirmation from `zk2`, so `zk2` is behind the quorum) I will see the value as "3" rather than "4". Does it break the sequential consistency?

Answer (score 5):

ZooKeeper uses a special atomic messaging protocol called **[ZooKeeper Atomic
Broadcast (ZAB)](http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.3.6/zookeeperInternals.html)**, which ensures that the local replicas in the ensemble (groups of Zookeeper servers) never diverge.

ZAB protocol is atomic, so the protocol guarantees that updates either succeed or fail.

In Zookeeper every write goes through the leader and leader generates a transaction id (called **zxid**) and assigns it to this write request.

A zxid is a long (64-bit) integer split into two parts:

- epoch
- counter

The zxid represents the order in which the writes are applied on all replicas.
The **epoch** represents the changes in leadership over time. Epochs refer to the period during which a given server exercised leadership. During an epoch, a leader broadcasts proposals and identifies each one according to the counter.

A write is considered successful if the leader receives the ack from the majority.

The zxid is used to keep servers synchronized and avoid the conflict you described.

[image]

Comment: I recently found out that zookeeper reads only reads from the zknode the client is connected to.  So if the zk2 node mentioned in the original post is the follower that did not send the ACK, does that mean the result will be "3". Read requests reads from the local zknode from (http://www.corejavaguru.com/bigdata/zookeeper/how-zookeeper-works)  Does ZAB prevent old data from being read via the non-acked followers?

Comment: This answer actually explains that some followers are outdated and doesn't explain the key detail being asked, which is how Zookeeper manages "single system image" for a given client.

Answer (score 0):

When connecting to a node, the client submits the latest zxid it's seen.  If this is newer than the last zxid the node has seen, it will refuse to connect.

So the scenario where client writes but then disconnects and reconnects to an outdated follower can't happen (reconnect is refused by the node).